# How to use vim in textarea in 2023? ItsAllText like

Tags: vim, firefox, chrome, browser

I remember how it was simple to edit textarea back in the dayZ with [itsalltex browser addon](https://github.com/docwhat/itsalltext), now I searched quite an hour which addon can replace this well known utility.

I found [ghostext](https://github.com/raghur/vim-ghost) (recommended from the github page of the author of `itsalltext`), and the doc is a bit vague about how to install the plugin. The github page tell to do:

add this

```
" Vim-plug
Plug 'raghur/vim-ghost', {'do': ':GhostInstall'}
```

So I Created `~/.vim/plugins/ghostext.vim` with this content.

Tried `:GhostStart`, but get error `unknown command GhostStart`

```
$ pip3 list  | grep vim
pynvim                0.4.3
```

The browser addon is well installed.

My `vim` have `+python3` support when I run `:ver`.

What does I need to install this plugin?

Comment: That `Plug` line is for installing with [the vim-plug plugin manager](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `vimrc` with another dependencies:

```
" Vim-plug 
call plug#begin()
    Plug 'roxma/nvim-yarp', v:version >= 800 && !has('nvim') ? {} : { 'on': [], 'for': [] }
    Plug 'roxma/vim-hug-neovim-rpc', v:version >= 800 && !has('nvim') ? {} : { 'on': [], 'for': [] }
    Plug 'raghur/vim-ghost', {'do': ':GhostInstall'}
call plug#end()
```

Then

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Then

```
:PlugInstall 
:q
```

then reload `vim` and:

```
:GhostStart
```